# Anyone have the Aspeed ast2050 vga working from a Tyan S7025?

Tags: server, xorg, x11

I have an Ubuntu natty 64bits installed (server edition with ubuntu-desktop installed to have gnome-desktop there (with no suggested packages) on a server using a Tyan S7025 board with an ntegrated VGA ASPEED ast2050.

The VGA works with a correct resolution, but it's very (really) slow. I've searched for the xserver-xorg-video-ast module, but it doesn't exists in the repositories. XORG logs complains about the lack of the ast module to be loaded.

Do you have this vga working somehow?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, although the card model is different. In the end, I downloaded the driver from ftp://x.org/pub/individual/driver/xf86-video-ast-0.91.10.tar.gz and built the driver from source. FYI, I had to install the xserver-xorg-dev package before I could build it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asus.com/Commercial_Servers_Workstations/P8BE4L/#support

Driver & Tools

Download and Install (run auto-update.sh )